# Spring integration. Propagate some headers through splitter

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a folowing chain of message processing.

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="acceptFileChannel" output-channel="validateMessageChannel">
    <int:error-channel ref="validateSplitTransformErrorChannel"/>
    <int:header name="originalFileName" expression="payload.getName()"/>
    <int:header name="originalFile" expression="payload"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int:service-activator input-channel="validateMessageChannel" output-channel="splitMessageChannel">
    <bean class="com.my.usual.ValidationService">
        <property name="schemaResource" value="classpath:/META-INF/xsd/locals_final_version.xsd"/>
    </bean>
</int:service-activator>

<int:splitter id="staxXmlSplitter" input-channel="splitMessageChannel"
              output-channel="payloadTypeRoutingChannel">
    <bean class="com.my.usual.XMLSplitter"/>
</int:splitter>

<int:payload-type-router input-channel="payloadTypeRoutingChannel">
    <int:mapping type="org.w3c.dom.Node" channel="afterSplitChannel"/>
    <int:mapping type="com.my.usual.SequenceSizeMessage" channel="barrier"/>
</int:payload-type-router>

<int:channel id="afterSplitChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<si-xml:xpath-router id="afterSplitRouter" input-channel="afterSplitChannel" evaluate-as-string="true">
    <si-xml:xpath-expression expression="local-name(/Act | /Partner)"/>
    <si-xml:mapping value="Act" channel="transformActChannel"/>
    <!--todo: for example of extending-->
    <si-xml:mapping value="Partner" channel="nullChannel"/>
</si-xml:xpath-router>
```

In this chain I set two message headers: `originalFileName` and `originalFile`.
Seems like simplest way to keep headers after splitting message by `com.my.usual.XMLSplitter` is override methodsomething like.

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldCopyRequestHeaders() {
    return true;
}
```

But what if I need only one header in splitted messages? I heed somehow read value of `originalFileName` and write it to each splitted messages.

I think I can write header by `willAddHeaders` and `addHeaders` methods of splitter. But I am not sure about scope of a splitter bean. So if it's a singleton and will be user concurrenly, how to keep original headers?

Can someone help me to find good solution?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear.

Look, you have `<int:header-enricher>` before `<int:splitter>`. This way you indeed write it only once to the original message. The nature of the splitter to copy all the request headers into each splitted item:

```
    Map<String, Object> messageHeaders = message.getHeaders();
    if (willAddHeaders(message)) {
        messageHeaders = new HashMap<>(messageHeaders);
        addHeaders(message, messageHeaders);
    }

    final Map<String, Object> headers = messageHeaders;
    final Object correlationId = message.getHeaders().getId();
    final AtomicInteger sequenceNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);

    Function<Object, AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?>> messageBuilderFunction =
            object -> createBuilder(object, headers, correlationId, sequenceNumber.getAndIncrement(), sequenceSize);
```

So, what you are looking for is there as out-of-the-box feature and all your message on the `payloadTypeRoutingChannel` will have those `originalFileName` and `originalFile` headers!

Comment: Yep. I's true. All headers was copied. Problem was in other place. I am forget to describe param for transformer. Thanks for your answer.